"Correct" definition of $\kappa$-closed poset
Compare the following two definitions:
(1) a poset is $\kappa$-closed if any decreasing sequence of length $<\kappa$ has a lower bound;
(2) a poset is $\kappa$-closed if any decreasing sequence of length $\leq\kappa$ has a lower bound.
Both of them are widely used, e.g., Kunen uses (1) and Jech uses (2). Which one is more "correct"? Although I first learned forcing from Kunen, I do feel that (2) is more natural. The disadvantage of (2), I guess, is that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible, we need to invent a new definition "$<\kappa$-closed" for posets such as $\mathrm{Add}(\kappa,1)$.
Another question is why are there two competing definitions for $\kappa$-closed, $\kappa$-directed closed, $\kappa$-distributive, but not for $\kappa$-cc, $\kappa$-saturated (model or Boolean algebra), $\kappa$-complete (ultrafilter), etc.? If someone uses (2) wouldn't it make more sense for them to define $\kappa$-cc as "every antichain has size $\leq\kappa$"?
